# Include local CSS files in a single vue component

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-component, single-page-application

Am building a Laravel vue SPA, I need to know How to include local CSS files in a single vue component only?

Comment: Do you refer to scoped CSS? Ref:https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html

Comment: i used scoped css but it only works if i refresh the page and still affect other components loaded via vue router

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `@import` available through `scss` like so:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  @import '../css/mycss.scss'; /* injected */
  @import '../css/mycss.css'; /* will use url import (do not use)*/
</style>
```

This may require that you add `node-sass` dependency and make some adjustments to your webpack configuration, if you don't already have it. If you're using a Vue cli generated project though, it is likely already included.

Note that if you want the css to be scoped, you should rename the extension to `.scss`, this way it will be handled by vue-loader. Importing a `.css` file is does not work the same way, and is treated as a url import.

Comment: Don't be afraid to nest the import under a css selector as well, it works!

Comment: important point is extension should be .scss

Answer (score 1):

You can import CSS file on component inside script tag

This worked for me:

```
<template>
</template>

<script>
import "@/assets/<file-name>.css";

export default {}
</script>
```